# output formatting of shell script - mysql

Tags: linux, bash, mysql

When I run this script

```
mysql -e "use sentry;
select   DISTINCT
concat(
'CREATE ROLE \`',
r.ROLE_NAME,
'\`;')
from
SENTRY_ROLE r
join SENTRY_ROLE_DB_PRIVILEGE_MAP rp on rp.ROLE_ID = r.ROLE_ID
join SENTRY_DB_PRIVILEGE p on p.DB_PRIVILEGE_ID = rp.DB_PRIVILEGE_ID
;" -u mysql_sel -p$Pass
```

I get output of

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| concat(
'CREATE ROLE `',
r.ROLE_NAME,
'`;') |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| CREATE ROLE `admin_role`;                               |
```

How can I get output of only

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| CREATE ROLE `admin_role`;                               |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysql -N` to skip column names on the output ASCII table.  To use your command line as an example:

```
mysql -N -e "use sentry;
select   DISTINCT
concat(
'CREATE ROLE \`',
r.ROLE_NAME,
'\`;')
from
SENTRY_ROLE r
join SENTRY_ROLE_DB_PRIVILEGE_MAP rp on rp.ROLE_ID = r.ROLE_ID
join SENTRY_DB_PRIVILEGE p on p.DB_PRIVILEGE_ID = rp.DB_PRIVILEGE_ID
;" -u mysql_sel -p$Pass
```